# In 2022, what is the expected behavior of an Apple TV 1st Generation?

Tags: appletv

Someone gave me a 1st Generation **Apple TV** they were going to put in the trash.

Curious to see if there's anything - at all, screen mirroring, screensavers, even a clock, etc - that it can be used for before taking it apart, I plugged it in and into a monitor, and got an off brand remote and batteries.

[image]

But when I powered it on, nothing came up on the screen. Not even the **Apple** logo, which is slightly peculiar - I'm assuming that even if it's totally obsolete, some sort of BIOS screen would have shown up?

And it shouldn't know - yet - that it's an obsolete device, since I haven't connected it to the wifi, right?

I just have the orange LED on the front that blinks.

**What should a Apple TV 1st generation behave like in 2022 when plugged in, and what does it mean when nothing appears on the screen?**

Comment: This: https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/547731/apple-tv-1st-generation.html?page=33 seems to indicate that it is stuck in "starting up." I would venture to say that they gave it to you because it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: @SteveChambers possible! I’m having a hard time seeing the document, is there a way to reset it?

Answer (score 2):

"Obsolete" just means that it's more than 7 years since Apple stopped selling them, and Apple won't repair it. There's no internal clock that makes them die, like Blade Runner.

A fully functional 1st generation Apple TV should, at least, continue to run whatever version of tvOS it has: you should see apps, settings, screensavers, etc. Whether the apps still work -- because say Netflix has changed the format/protocol that they send out -- is another matter.

The fact that you don't see anything, and have a blinking front light suggests there's some problem with the ATV. If they came with mechanical hard drives, that would be the first thing to look at.